# How does Light Yagami manage to hide a portable TV inside the chips packet?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-note

When L is monitoring the Yagami's household with cameras and mics in *Death Note*, Light has no direct access to the news.

In order to continue killing criminals who are shown in the news, Light hides and uses a portable TV inside the chips packet.

How was he able to hide the TV inside the packet without L or the monitoring team noticing the same?

EDIT: The question is not about how the TV was able to fit in the packet. I want to know how Light was able to put the TV in the packet without anyone noticing that he is, in fact, putting a TV inside the chips packet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that he bought a pack of chips and mini-TV somewhere outside the room, where noone was able to see him. He opened the package, put mini-TV inside and resealed the package, probably using smoothing iron. Then he could open the package like any other without suspicion in his room.

[Source from deathnote wiki:](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Trash)

> Ryuk tells Light of the location of each camera in his room. Light then sets up the potato chips to open up facing a blind spot among the cameras. **Earlier that day, he put a tiny T.V. into the potato chip bag where he could see it**. He pretends to do homework problems with his right hand while reaching into the potato chip bag with his left and writing down the names of criminals he sees on T.V. When he's done, he throws away the potato chip bag.

So he either did what I described or just brought opened bag into his room with TV in it. I bet it isn't described in more detail neither in manga, anime, action movie or any other media, because it's a minor, unimportant detail.

Comment: Any credible source or just an assumption? If I remember correctly, he takes the packet from the snacks rack in the kitchen.

Comment: @CinCout only an assumption, can't confirm because I am at work now

Comment: Until you add the source, this is more suited to be a comment.

Comment: @CinCout edited my original post to add source

Answer (score 1):

Light put the TV in the bag earlier that day. In the manga he explains to Ryuk that he is the only one in the family who eats this particular flavor of chips. This way he could be sure that none of his family members would open the bag and see the hidden mini TV.